# Getting white areas on my console when I use function?

Tags: c++, cmd, cout

I am getting some weird white areas on my cmd everytime I run my program and use a particular function. The white areas really have no effect on the program whatsoever other than it looks ugly and distracting.

I think in this circumstance a snapshot is needed:
[image: Screenshot]

Here is the function I'm using:

```
void ClearScr()
{
std::cout << std::string(50,'\n');
//all it does is simply creates 50 new lines so that the information doesn't become overwehlming
}
```

I also did try this:

```
void ClearScr()
{
  for(int i = 0; i < 50 ; i++){
    std::cout << "\n";
  }
}
```

Comment: I edited my question, I think I tried your method and it didn't work.

Comment: Interesting problem. +1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're on Windows, which means that 'standard' behaviour does not always apply.

Here is a link to a [Microsoft MSDN item](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682022(v=vs.85).aspx) on how to clear the console.

Comment: Will go ahead and try to incorporate this into my project, thank you.

Comment: Okay, so the first option works fine. The problem that I have with using it is that I have read that it is taboo or bad practice to use system("anything") when programming. 

Is this correct? I tried to incorporate the entire file in example two but I couldn't do it.

Comment: You should only `system()` out to programs that you can guarantee will be available to your program. `cls` is a fundamental part of the Windows installation so it should be fine. It's not super-efficient, but you're doing console IO anyway so that's not a consideration in this case.